# Adding a watermark to Microsoft Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, watermark

I am attempting to add a watermark to Microsoft Word headers using VSTO and `Shapes.AddTextEffect`, it seems to add correctly until I check the Different First Page and Different Odd & Even Pages check-boxes in Header and Footer design.

It seems to be just adding it to the Odd Page Header, I'm not sure why as I'm passing in the different header types, find my code below.

```
private static void UpdateWatermark(ComObjectWrapper<Document> doc, string watermarkText, string watermarkName, Style style)
    {
        foreach (Section section in doc.Resource.Sections)
        { 
            if (!watermarkText.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                InsertWatermark(section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary], section, watermarkText, watermarkName + (int)WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary, style);
                if (section.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter == -1)
                    InsertWatermark(section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage], section, watermarkText, watermarkName + (int)WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage, style);
                if (section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter == -1)
                    InsertWatermark(section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages], section, watermarkText, watermarkName + (int)WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages, style);
            }
        }
    }

 private static void InsertWatermark(HeaderFooter header, Section section, string watermarkText, string watermarkName, Style style)
    {
        var wm = header.Shapes.AddTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, watermarkText,
            style.WatermarkStyle.FontFamily,
            style.WatermarkStyle.FontSize ?? 72,
            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, header.Range);
        wm.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
        wm.Name = watermarkName;
        wm.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)WdColor.wdColorGray10;
        wm.Fill.BackColor.RGB = (int)WdColor.wdColorGray10;
        wm.Fill.Transparency = 0.2f;
        wm.Fill.Solid();
        wm.Rotation = -45;

        wm.RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;
        wm.RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;
        wm.Height = style.WatermarkStyle.Height != null
            ? (float)style.WatermarkStyle.Height
            : section.PageSetup.PageHeight - 400;
        wm.Width = section.PageSetup.PageWidth - 200;
        wm.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
        wm.WrapFormat.Side = WdWrapSideType.wdWrapBoth;
        wm.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapNone;

        wm.Left = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
        wm.Top = (float)WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
        wm.Visible = MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
    }
```

Comment: Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> `if (section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter == -1)`

Is this enum correct? 
I havent earned commenting yet =)

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft Word seems to have -1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: try odd and even seperatly, with a document that already has an header for both cases. Maybe Office is derpy.

Comment: There's 3 HeaderFooter types, it doesn't show on the first page either, it doesn't seem to be listening to the HeaderFooter type's, yet it does when adding an actual header or footer this way

Comment: as i said try it with an enabled document, maybe a setting in your document blocks it

Comment: Seems to be a similar case, regardless of which settings are selected with headers prior to applying the watermark, it's not applying the watermark to all pages with the different header footer types

Comment: workaround: try uneven with your even+uneven method

Just poking ideas

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to make a difference, unfortunately